# Is there way to write the following integral representations of integer zeta values in a general form?

Tags: definite-integrals, riemann-zeta

How do you write this as a general formula for all integer zeta values greater than $0$?

$$\zeta(1)=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-x}dx$$
$$\zeta(2)=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1}{1-xy}dxdy$$
$$\zeta(3)=\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1}{1-xyz}dxdydz$$

$$\zeta(n) = ?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\zeta(n) = \int_{[0,1]^n} \dfrac{1}{1-\prod_{i=1}^n x_i} dx_1 \ldots dx_n$$

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know how to write the multiple integrals!

Comment: Also, can you write the dx's as a product or is that incorrect?